# How do I get a datepicker to default to "Pick a Date"?

Tags: c#, wpf, date, data-binding, datepicker

I have several DatePickers and many of them will not have a date by default.  When there is data for the given DatePicker I want it to show the date, but if not, I want it to show the default "Select a Date" text when my data is empty for that date.

Before I created a DataBinding for the DatePicker, it showed this text on all of my DatePickers, but after I created a DataBinding it's to a DateTime value, which can't be a null value.  Is there a different data type that does accept a null value that the DatePicker would accept, or is there a better way for the DatePicker to display the "Select a Date?"

I'm kinda new to programming so please forgive if I didn't make it clear or include some required information.  I can provide whatever is needed.  Just ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`SelectedDate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `DatePicker` is of type `DateTime?`, so it's [nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).

If you have this in your view model:

```
public DateTime DateTimeInVm { get; set; }
```

And this in your view:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DateTimeInVm}"></DatePicker>
```

Then yes, the output will be:

[image: wrongoutput]

Because as you said `DateTime` is a `struct` so it can't be `null` and will be initialized to `DateTime.MinValue`.

But if you have this in the view model:

```
public DateTime? DateTimeInVm { get; set; }
```

The result will be:

[image: correctoutput]

So try to change the property you're binding to to a nullable `DateTime`.

Comment: Is there an advantage to bind the datepicker vs use the Name property ?

Comment: Yes, lets say you have a viewmodel with `FromSelectedDate` and `ToSelectedDate` properties and two `DatePicker`s in the view bound to those properties. If you use a binding when you change the from and to dates in the UI (by clicking in the `DatePicker`) those properties will be automatically updated. If you don't bind them then you have to attach an event handler to check if the `SelectedDate` is changed and then in the code-behind update the appropriate values. Also if you want to follow the MVVM pattern, you can't live without bindings :) It's basically the selling point of WPF.

Comment: Tanks a lot. So if i bind my DatePicker to DateTimeInVm like in your example,  it will alow me to use it directly without using the SelectedDate Property of the DatePicker. I only see this difference ?

Comment: Yes, basically you have to bind to a nullable `DateTime`. So the property you're binding to has to have the type `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>` (they're the same). Because `default(DateTime?)` is `null` the `Select a date` text will be shown in the `DatePicker` in case of "empty dates".

Comment: I was not aware of the Nullable<> or the DateTime? types.  Does adding a ? at the end of any struct make it nullable?

Comment: Yes, if you add a `?` at the end of a value type (struct), you make it nullable. So `DateTime? dt = null;` is perfectly valid. Also `default(DateTime?)` is null.

Comment: Thank you buy the way.  I forgot to say that in my previous comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to bind your DatePicker? Because you can simply give it a name  and you will be able to give it null value (for Select a date) or set date:

AXML:

```
<DatePicker Name="MyDatePicker"/>
```

C#

```
MyDatePicker.SelectedDate = null; // will show "Select a date" 
MyDatePicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today; //will show today's date
```

Comment: I bind it so that it shows the DateTime that is stored in the data file (in my case an xml file that is loaded upon startup).  If the specific field from the xml file is blank, then I want the DatePicker to show "Select a date"; if it is not I want it to populate with the DateTime data.

Comment: Have you solve your problem ? Szabolcs Dézsi Method should work